Stripe Apps OAuth integration not working according to docs?
I am referring these docs to create an OAuth integration using Stripe App :
https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-apps/api-authentication/oauth
Now, according to the docs we need to set the stripe-app.json of the app to something like this:
{
  "id": "com.example.my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "Your Stripe App",
  "icon": "./[YOUR_APP]_icon_32.png",
  "permissions": [
    // Your app permissions here
  ],
  "stripe_api_access_type": "oauth",
  "distribution_type": "public",
  "allowed_redirect_uris": [
    // Your redirect URIs here
  ]
}

This is what my manifest file looks like:
{
  "id": "app.myapp.app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "name": "Finlens",
  "icon": "",
  "permissions": [],
  "ui_extension": {
    "views": [
      {
        "viewport": "stripe.dashboard.customer.detail",
        "component": "App"
      }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": {
      "connect-src": null,
      "image-src": null,
      "purpose": ""
    }
  },
  "allowed_redirect_uris": [
    "https://app.myapp.com",
    "https://app.myapp.com",
    "https://app-sandbox.myapp.com"
  ],
  "stripe_api_access_type": "oauth",
  "distribution_type": "public"
}


But, if I have my distribution_type set to public . On running stripe apps upload
This error occurs:
stripe apps upload

 ⓘ  You have selected public distribution for this app. Please note the
    following:
    * After you upload, you cannot change the distribution to private.
    * You can only upload one public app per Stripe account.

Would you like to proceed: y

⬆ You are about to upload your app to finlens-landing.netlify.app

Name:    Finlens
ID:      app.finlens.app
Version: 0.0.2

? Would you like to proceed✔ Built files for production
✔ Packaged files for upload
× Failed to upload Finlens
Request failed, status=400, body={
  "error": {
    "message": "9:Because your account is a connect platform, you cannot choose the public distribution at this time.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_JE77rE1IvcYxiL?t=1712054037",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Now my question is, what does the message 9:Because your account is a connect platform, you cannot choose the public distribution at this time. mean ?
I've followed the steps given by the docs, but it's not working

I'm having a similar issue. Did you figure this out?

facing same issue - what did you do?

I emailed this issue to Stripe Support, this is probably a gatekeeping mechanism used by Stripe.
This is the email response from Stripe Support.
Hello there, 
 
Thank you for your patience. It looks like your usage was tagged as a Connect Platform vs a Connect Extension (the latter’s functionality has been replaced with the migration to Stripe Apps). 

 

This is purely an internal tag that we can change with your permission — from what we observe of your usage, this seems like the right choice to make unless you are creating connected accounts and moving money between them. By making this change, nothing about your current usage or customer adoption will change or be interrupted. Before selecting public distribution, please keep in mind that at this time you cannot change the id of your app.

 

Please let us know if we have your permission to make this change or if you have any questions!
 


I had the same issue but solved it by creating a new account and then registering the  Stripe App again after ‘stripe login’ to connect to the new account.
Then it allows upload and registering with marketplace. (after creating a unique app name as the old one is connected to the old account)
The issue is that I had a Connect Account (allowing transactions etc, and I was using it for that purpose) instead of creating a developer account to create my app in.
Very bad Stripe errors did not help to work it out.
